# Copy file to server with specific port using scp in Linux

Tags: linux, centos, port, scp

If I want to copy file from server to my local OS I use this:

```
scp -P 60385 root@162.243.120.200:/myserver/somefile.txt /mylocaladdress/.
```

But how do I do the opposite?

I tried this:

```
scp /mylocaladdress/somefile.txt root@162.243.120.200:/myserver/. -P 60835
```

And this:

```
scp /mylocaladdress/somefile.txt -P 60835 root@162.243.120.200:/myserver/.
```

But I'm getting this error

```
ssh: connect to host 162.243.120.200 port 22: Connection refused
lost connection
```

I have `Ubuntu` on local and `CentOS` 6.5 on the server

Comment: scp -P 24 local_file user@server:/path/ work fine. man scp show---> scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port]   [-S program] [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2

Comment: bsides scp you could use nc - netcat -  on server nc -l 2001 < /tmp/file.txt  on slave nc master 2001 > /tmp/file.txt. or if you wanted to do it recursively tar -cvzf - folder | nc -l 2001  on master and on slave nc master 2001 |tar -xvzf -

Answer (score 2, accepted):

man scp show:

```
      scp [-1246BCpqrv] [-c cipher] [-F ssh_config] [-i identity_file] [-l limit] [-o ssh_option] [-P port] [-S program] [[user@]host1:]file1 ... [[user@]host2:]file2
```

Port it's before files and host